# Does FIPS OpenSSL work with Boost ASIO?

Tags: boost, openssl, fips, asio

I've built the fips mode OpenSSL using OpenSSL version 1.0.2d and the fips canister with version 2.0.13. The whole thing compiles and links successfully to create a Windows 32-bit version of the libeay32 and ssleay32 lib and dll files.

I've created a small sample program (just a console program in VS2010) that can run correctly - just setting OpenSSL into fips mode and printing errors if anything goes wrong.

However, when I link those same lib/dll files in the actual program I'm developing things don't work at all. The program is an executable that loads dll modules for functionality. One of those dll modules is the one that links to the OpenSSL library. That dll module also uses Boost asio. When my program starts, it can't load its own dll module that uses the OpenSSL dlls.

I thought there might be a dependency issue (something not found) that was preventing the load. That's what lead me to creating the small console sample. It works using the same linkage settings and files.

If I build the OpenSSL without the fips canister - just 'regular' OpenSSL version 1.0.2d, the resulting lib/dll files work fine in my application.

So, I'm wondering if there is something that the boost library might be doing that is preventing the fips OpenSSL dlls from loading correctly.

Has anyone heard of anything like this?

Thanks.